# What is the RDUSB00E6Setupd process running by launchd

Tags: macbook-pro, launchd

What is the RDUSB00E6Setupd process running by launchd in a Macbook Pro with  Mavericks? I can't find any information about this and my computer is running quite slow, trying to figure out what is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on [Google](http://www.iboostup.com/app/jp.co.roland.rdusb00e6.uninstaller):

> Uninstaller (jp.co.roland.rdusb00e6.uninstaller) is a Mac OS X
>   software application that has been discovered and submitted by users
>   of iBoostUp. The latest version that our iBoostUp users have reported
>   seeing on their systems is Uninstaller 1.0.0.

It sounds like you are trying to install the Uninstaller!

If you are not to be blamed :) go to Activity Monitor and kill the process.

Open terminal and search for the file

> mdfind -name rdusb00e6

Comment: i did a google search and didn't get any result, now, when i googled again it just shows me the link to my question.. weird. Anyway thanks for your reply, that's what i was looking for.

Comment: here is my link http://www.iboostup.com/app/jp.co.roland.rdusb00e6.uninstaller

Comment: The fact is that i am not uninstalling anything, but the process is run by launchd. Might this be a virus or something? (I own some roland stuff, usb keyboard, etc..)

Comment: I do not think it is a virus, but someone is trying to install it. So find the file with mdfind and kill it..burn in hell :)

Comment: After killing the process in Activity Monitor and rm the entire /Library/StartupItems/RDUSB00E6Startup/ folder my computer is working as expected. Might not be a virus but obviously there was something wrong with that. Thanks Buscar웃 for your help.

Comment: It could have been a part of a Package you installed.

Comment: Probably, i use to try many audio devices, some of them need drivers installed.

Answer (score 1):

This is from a Roland/Edirol Audio interface. So not a virus.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review